# Why my accept() failed due to a bad file descriptor?

Tags: c, network-programming

I am making a concurrent platform independent client-server program and my UNIX `accept()` failed due to a bad file descriptor yet winsock works fine. I tested it on both Linux and Windows.

```
int child, len, option = 1, rd;
SOCKET client_socket;
struct sockaddr_in client_addr;

SOCKET server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (server_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to initialize server socket");
    return -1;
}
else printf("Socket successfully created.\n");

if (setsockopt(server_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &option, sizeof(int)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "setsockopt for SO_REUSEADDR failed.\n");
}
else printf("Set SO_REUSEADDR: ON\n");

struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

if (bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to bind to %s port %d\n", inet_ntoa(server_addr.sin_addr), PORT);
    perror("");
    close(server_socket);
    return -1;
}
else printf("Bind successful.\n");

if (listen(server_socket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to put server socket into listen state.\n");
    close(server_socket);
    return -1;
}
else printf("Listening on %s:%d.\n", inet_ntoa(server_addr.sin_addr), PORT);
socklen_t cli_addr_size = sizeof(client_addr);

while (true)
{
    //HERE
    client_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, (socklen_t*) &cli_addr_size);
    if (client_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Accept failed with %d\n", client_socket);
        perror("");
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Client %s:%d joined the server.\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
        child = fork();
        if (child < 0)
        {
            perror("ERROR on fork");
            exit(-1);
        }
        printf("fork() returned %d.\n", child);
        if (child == 0)
        {
            close(server_socket);
            rd = recv(client_socket, rcvbuf, sizeof(rcvbuf), 0);
            if (rd < 0)
                perror("Error in receiving message");
            else if (rd == 0)
                printf("Client %s disconnected\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr));
            else
            {
                sprintf(sndbuf, "Client %s:%d: %s\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port),
                    rcvbuf);
                puts(sndbuf);
                if (send(client_socket, sndbuf, sizeof(sndbuf), 0) < 0)
                {
                    perror("Error in sending message");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have included the chunk of code to prevent guesswork.
Is there also a better way to implement `fork()` for example by graceful prevention of orphans?
Improvements are welcome.

Comment: The wall-to-wall conditional compilation makes it hard to see what's going on.  Are you running into the problem when `NTENV` is defined or when it is not defined?  You should eliminate the irrelevant code to help create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  If the problem happens with both, you should probably still choose one or the other and show only that.

Comment: Observation: since you have `return -1;` in the `if` block, you could lose the `else` in `} else printf("Socket successfully created.\n");` and simply place the `printf()` on its own line — IMO, that would be easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first time a connection is accepted and a child is forked, the child process is continuing the `while (true)` after it finished processing the connection.  And since it closed the listening socket, it gets an error when calling `accept`.

The child should call `_exit` when it's done with its processing:

```
    if (child == 0)
    {
        close(server_socket);
        rd = recv(client_socket, rcvbuf, sizeof(rcvbuf), 0);
        if (rd < 0)
            perror("Error in receiving message");
        else if (rd == 0)
            printf("Client %s disconnected\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr));
        else
        {
            sprintf(sndbuf, "Client %s:%d: %s\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port),
                rcvbuf);
            puts(sndbuf);
            if (send(client_socket, sndbuf, sizeof(sndbuf), 0) < 0)
            {
                perror("Error in sending message");
            }
        }
        _exit(0);
    }
```

You probably also want to have the parent periodically `wait` for child processes so you don't have zombie processing sitting around.
}

Comment: This does not allow a client to send multiple messages...

Comment: @user14773854: If you want the client to process multiple messages, put a loop around the receive and send operations.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is `_exit(0)` part of the loop?

Comment: @user14773854 — No.  The `_exit()` function kills the process; it does not return and the loop could not continue.